# Auth guard [:api] is not defined?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

When I use `auth:api` guard for the logout route, I'm facing the following exception:

> Auth guard [:api] is not defined

I have already implemented registration/login APIs, but I am facing this error with logout API, which I had protected using `auth::api`.

`config/auth.php`:

```php
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

`routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login','AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup','AuthController@signup');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth::api'], function () {
        Route::get('logout','AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user','AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

I should be able to log out the user.

Comment: `auth::api` is incorrect, remove one of the colons `auth:api`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra colon in your code, that's why it is trying to find the guard `:api`.

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#middleware-parameters):

> Middleware parameters may be specified when defining the route by
>   separating the middleware name and parameters with a :. Multiple
>   parameters should be delimited by commas:

```
Route::put('post/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->middleware('role:editor');
```

So in your case it would be:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('login','AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup','AuthController@signup');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        Route::get('logout','AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user','AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `Laravel 9+` and `Passport`, you need to implemented this inside the `guard` array on `config/auth.php` file:

```php
'guards' => [
    ...

    // you need to implement this
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => true,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it seems that i forgot to change Authentication Defaults
so in config/auth.php change this

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        ....
    ],
```

into this

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        ....
    ],
```